# Facebook sharing from Safari

Tags: safari

Why is Facebook missing from the list of ways to share a page in Safari?  That option used to exist before the latest update.  When I'm directed to the extensions box Facebook is not there.

Answer (score 4):

Facebook and Twitter sharing have been removed in Mojave.

Comment: it's mostly about security and privacy. Check this article -> https://www.macrumors.com/2018/06/06/macos-mojave-drops-login-options-twitter-facebook/